# mysql the fastest way in using NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql query

```
SELECT a.*, b.ID AS ID_OUTLET
FROM nomor_logo a LEFT JOIN outlet b 
ON b.NOMOR_LOGO_WARALABA = a.ID
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
AND a.ID NOT IN (SELECT NOMOR_LOGO_WARALABA FROM outlet)
```

the problem is that it takes a lot of time since it using NOT IN.
Is there a way to make it faster in writing the query? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If in the NOT IN you're trying to compare the id of a and b then I think you could do it this way :

```
SELECT a.*, b.ID AS ID_OUTLET
FROM nomor_logo a LEFT JOIN outlet b 
ON b.NOMOR_LOGO_WARALABA = a.ID
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
AND a.ID != b.NOMOR_LOGO_WARALABA
```

Comment: @Faiz anything else needed to mark this as answered? :)